# Implement Web page Segmention

Tags: html

How could I implement  web page segmentation(any type-Vision based/Layout based/Reappearance based)?? 
Any implemented examples or useful links?
Thanks in advance..

Comment: You need to be more clear about the question, otherwise you will get a lot of answers that have nothing to do with what you want to know.
Here is my guess:
How do I layout a web page differently for mobile devices? If this is correct, update the question.

Comment: @Mark :Thanks for the advice..

Answer (score 0):

Simple way might be media queries:

```
<div class="content"></div>
```

Then in the css you set a standard style and override it if the screen is small. This is not only for mobile, if you re size your browser it will take affect but it will work on all small screen displays.

```
.content{width:400px;}
@media screen and (max-width: 400px){
    .content {width:200px;}
}
```

There are other ways of course, but for a basic implementation this will do what you need.

Comment: Hi Mark, can you help me with my project...Abstract is given [here](http://getitfast.net16.net/pxc3880801.pdf). My email ID is 'kader.chalil@gmail.com'. Thanks in advance.